# PGI Compiler error "Can't find include file bits/c++config.h"

Tags: header, pgi

I am writing in C and using the pgi compiler with Ubuntu OS. I want to include a header file with functions that I created. In my code I have

```
#include "myfunctions.h"
```

However when I compile I get the error

```
PGC-F-0206-Can't find include file bits/c++config.h (/opt/pgi/linux86-64/16.7/include/bits/c++config.h: 22)
```

The directory in the parentheses is exactly where bits/c++config.h file is located on my workstation. Also, if I take out the "#include' statement in my code, everything runs fine. Furthermore I've even added "/opt/pgi/linux86-64/16.7/include" to my path, and I still get the error above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out the problem. I had other include files in the "myfunctions.h" header that were missing.